# Timeout Notification Node Dilemna - Need a workaround

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am a Newbie to WMB and We have a requirement for Kicking Off a Msg Flow at 10 P.M each night.

After alot of Googling, I have suggested 2 ways to them - 
1. Use a CronJob to put a msg on the Input Q to start the flow. 
2. Use Timeout Notification node.

They have declined option 1 saying that IBM doesn't support cron jobs anymore, so we can't put that on the server.

For option 2, they are still fine but I have a question - Today i deploy the flow at the exact same time when I want it to et triggered after 24 Hrs but what happens when the Server is rebooted or the Flow is Stopped and started. 
Will the timer also start again from that moment and If Yes is there any Workaround this problem of rebooting or restarting that can be followed, so the flow is kicked off on the exact same time at 10 P.M irrespective even if it was redeployed or something like that.

We also have TWS in our environment, But I could not find any Integration documents or scenarios of TWS integration with IIB, Could you kindly give your valuable advices or comments - How can I reach to an efficient solution.

Thanks

Sumit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the timer will start when the flow containing the Timeout Notification starts.

A workaround could be to construct a flow that starts with a Timeout Notification, and in a Compute node connected directly to the output of the Timeout Notification, you check the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and only continue executing the flow if it is around the right time. To make this work the Timeout Notification should have a timeout value set, that allows for the required precision of the instant.

Answer (score 0):

Use timer control node to pass specify timer to trigger

And for that particular the timer notification node will receive message and kick starts